# Maximal critical points of differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis

Writing down the solution of the exercise paper for my teaching duties (analysis 2 for mathematics) I got stuck in an exercise that is surprisingly difficult (at least for me). Here is the text of my problem.

$\textbf{Problem:}$ Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function. Is that possible that $f$ has only two distinct critical points that are both global maxima?